# Find a non-trivial polynomial which has all integers as zeros modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

This is an exercise from the book "Einführung in die algebraische Zahlentheorie" by Alexander Schmidt.
Let $p$ be a prime number. And let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients such that it is not the zero polynomial modulo $p$ ($f \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$). But such that $f(a)\equiv 0 \pmod p$ for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Multiply that by $x$?

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the hint. I will remove the $f(x) = x^{p-1} - 1$ from the question to allow for a more non-trivial answer.

Comment: Try the product $\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} (x-i)$.

Comment: Indeed, the set of such polynomials is exactly the set of multiples of $x^p-p = \prod_{i=0}^{p-1} (x-i)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that $f\in F_p[X]$ is a non-zero polynomial with all $a\in F_p$ as roots. When $a\in F_p$ is a root, $(x-a)$ is a factor, thus $f(x)=g(x)\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} (x-i)$ for some non-zero $g\in F_p[X]$. We also see that every polynomial on the form $g(x)\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} (x-i)$ has every $a\in F_p$ as a root. We conclude that the polynomials are precisely the ones on the form: $$g(x)\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} (x-i),$$ where $g\not\equiv 0$.

Comment: Welcome, Frederick. In effect, the theory of finite fields says that every finite extension of the prime field $\mathbb F_p$ has $p^n$ elements and that in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$ there exists a unique subfield with as many elements as the considered extension of  $\mathbb F_p$ and that is constituted by the roots of the polynomial $f(X)=X^{p^n}-X$.